# Itext PDF 5.5 navigate to an instance of a text upon clicking a link

Tags: annotations, itext

Is there a way to have a multiple click here link at the bottom of the PDF and upon clicking the link navigate to corresponding sections in the same PDF.

Click here to go to section 1 - Text1
Click here to go to Section 2 - Text 2

Upon clicking these user should navigate to the Text 1 and Text 2 respectively which is in the same PDF

My case I have products listed category wise in my PDF. Below the user can view products chosen. While viewing the selected products if user clicks on a certain product it has to navigate the user back to that section in the same PDF. Any help in implementing this logic is much appreciated

Comment: This is pretty simple. What have you tried? Are you using iText 7 or an older version? (Older versions are no longer supported.) Did you read the tutorials?

Comment: @Bruno Considering the question title I doubt he is using iText 7.

Comment: @mkl OK, I overlooked that. Evenso, my answer explains that `setLocalGoto()` and `setLocalDestination()` should be used on a `Chunk` object. That should already help the OP in the right direction.

Comment: @Bruno Yes, indeed, the answer should be helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for this option. But in my case I have a list of links like Mobile, Tablet, laptop displayed one below the other. And upon clicking the Mobile link it should search for the text Mobile in the entire document n take the user to that line. Similarly when I click the other 2 it should search the entire document to match that exact words and navigate the user to that. It is possible to include a generic code piece to attain this.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    document.add(
        new Paragraph("Where's Waldo?")
            .setAction(PdfAction.createGoTo("Waldo")));
    document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
    document.add(
        new Paragraph("Here's Waldo!")
            .setDestination("Waldo"));
    document.close();
}
```

On the first page, I have the text `"Where's Waldo?"`. I add a link annotation to this text with a GoTo action using the `setAction()` and the `createGoTo()` method. I use the `String` `"Waldo"` as the name of the destination.

On the next page, I add the text `"Here's Waldo!"` and I define this text as the destination of a GoTo action referring to the name `"Waldo"` with the `setDestination()` method.

Now when I click on `"Where's Waldo?"` on the first page, the viewer jumps to the text `"Here's Waldo!"` on the second page.

**Important if you are still using iText 5:**

The snippet in this answer requires iText 7. If you need an iText 5 solution, please be aware that iText 5 is no longer supported. The code for iText 5 is different, but the principle is similar: you define two `Chunk` objects. You use the [`setLocalGoto()`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html#setLocalGoto-java.lang.String-) method on one `Chunk` and the [`setLocalDestination()`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html#setLocalDestination-java.lang.String-) method on the other one. See http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html